# Exponential Variance Shadow Mapping - implementation

Tags: opengl, glsl, shadow-mapping

I use a variance shadow mapping with a "standard" light bleeding fix in my graphics engine which is based on deferred rendering.. I have a single shadow map for a directional light beacause a test scene is relatively small. Saving depth looks like this:

```
float moment1 = gl_FragCoord.z;
float moment2 = moment1 * moment1;
outColor = vec2(moment1, moment2);
```

Then I perform a separable gaussian blur on that texture.

Shadow test:

```
float Chebyshev(vec2 moments, float mean, float minVariance)
{
    float shadow = 1.0f;
    if(mean <= moments.x)
    {
        shadow = 1.0f;
        return shadow;
    }
    else
    {
        float variance = moments.y - (moments.x * moments.x);
        variance = max(variance, minVariance);
        float d = mean - moments.x;
        shadow = variance / (variance + (d * d));
        float amount = 0.3f;
        shadow =  clamp((shadow - amount) / (1.0f - amount), 0.0f, 1.0f); // standard light bleeding fix
        return shadow;
    }
}

vec4 shadowCoord = shadowMatrix * vec4(viewSpacePosition, 1.0f); 
vec2 moments = texture(ShadowMap, shadowCoord.xy).xy;
float minVariance = 0.000001f;
float shadow = Chebyshev(moments, shadowCoord.z, minVariance);
```

I found a interesting technique - Exponential Variance Shadow Mapping which should provides better light bleeding fix. Here is saving depth for that technique:

```
float positiveExponent = 40.0f;
float negativeExponent = 5.0f
float depth = gl_FragCoord.z;
vec2 exponents = vec2(positiveExponent, negativeExponent);
depth = 2.0f * depth - 1.0f;
float pos = exp(exponents.x * depth);
float neg = -exp(-exponents.y * depth);
vec2 warpDepth = (pos, neg);
outColor = vec4(warpDepth, warpDepth * warpDepth);
```

How to implement a shadow test for that technique ? Here is my attempt:

```
float positiveExponent = 40.0f;
float negativeExponent = 5.0f;
vec2 exponents = vec2(positiveExponent, negativeExponent);

vec2 warpDepth(float depth)
{
    depth = 2.0f * depth - 1.0f;
    float pos = exp(exponents.x * depth);
    float neg = -exp(-exponents.y * depth);
    vec2 wDepth = vec2(pos, neg);
    return wDepth;
}

float Chebyshev(vec2 moments, float mean, float minVariance)
{
    float shadow = 1.0f;
    if(mean <= moments.x)
    {
        shadow = 1.0f;
        return shadow;
    }
    else
    {
        float variance = moments.y - (moments.x * moments.x);
        variance = max(variance, minVariance);
        float d = mean - moments.x;
        shadow = variance / (variance + (d * d));
        return shadow;
    }
}

vec4 shadowCoord = shadowMatrix * vec4(viewSpacePosition, 1.0f);
vec4 moments = texture(ShadowMap, shadowCoord.xy).xyzw;
vec2 posMoments = vec2(moments.x, moments.z);
vec2 negMoments = vec2(moments.y, moments.w);
vec2 wDepth = warpDepth(shadowCoord.z);
//float minVariance = 0.000001f;
//Edit
vec2 depthScale = 0.0001f * exponents * wDepth;
vec2 minVariance = depthScale * depthScale;
float posResult = Chebyshev(posMoments, wDepth.x, minVariance.x);
float negResult = Chebyshev(negMoments, wDepth.y, minVariance.y);
shadow = min(posResult, negResult);
```

Unfortunately it doesn't remove light bleeding. Did I do something wrong ? Maybe I should calculate two different minVariance based on the positive and negative exponents ?

**Edit1:**
Calculating minVariance this way:

```
vec2 depthScale = 0.0001f * exponents * wDepth;
vec2 minVariance = depthScale * depthScale;
float posResult = Chebyshev(posMoments, wDepth.x, minVariance.x);
float negResult = Chebyshev(negMoments, wDepth.y, minVariance.y);
```

gives better results but light bleeding is still quite visible.

**Edit2:**
Light bleeding:
EVSM with minVariance which is calculated as above gives better result than VSM without standard light bleeding fix, but to get the best result I also use standard light bleeding fix with EVSM. A light bleeding fix is performed in Chebyshev function but maybe I should add it after following calculation: shadow = min(posResult, negResult) ?

EVSM causes small artifacts on the illuminated side of the objects so I add some glPolygonOffset when saving EVSM depth.

Comment: Looks like you have a typo here: `vec2 warpDepth = (pos, neg)` - should be `vec2(pos, neg`)

Comment: Thanks, but I immediately fixed that because I got glsl compiler errors. A problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: I would be glad to see a screenshot, Irbis!

Answer (score 5):

Variance shadow mapping, plainly put, just suffers from these light bleeding issues.

I personally prefer to implement ESM (check out page 257 of ShaderX6) as the memory pressure is half of the VSM map and the artifacts are much less abrasive to me: (The very beginning of the shadow is a bit too bright.)

With this said, here is a (rather old) PDF full of great techniques to get you thinking. (or just to show you the algorithm if you don't have ShaderX6) http://developer.download.nvidia.com/presentations/2008/GDC/GDC08_SoftShadowMapping.pdf

In my current engine, I have a hybrid which is basically ESM, but uses the 2-moment (or higher) shadow map to compute the variance and reduce the ESM artifacts at the places where the occluder is too close to the receiver.